# nearest neighbor mapping of 1D index for 2D array into a smaller 2D array

Tags: c, pointers, indexing, multidimensional-array, nearest-neighbor

This is in C.

I have two 2D arrays, ArrayA and ArrayB, that sample the same space.  B samples a different attribute than ArrayA less frequently than ArrayA, so it is smaller than A.

Just to try to define some variables:
ArrayA: SizeAX by SizeAY, indexed by indexA for a position posAX, posAY
ArrayB: SizeBX by SizeAY, indexed by indexB for a position posBX, posBY

ArrayA and ArrayB are pointers to the start of the array, where the row of X's is stored first, then Y is incremented, and the next row of X's is stored (Y=1)

So I need to set indexB from a given indexA, such that it is a nearest neighbor sample, to associate with indexA's value.

Here's where I am (correct any errors please! Note that I am starting at index 0):
If ArrayA is 9x9 and ArrayB is 3x3:
(posX,posY)
posA 0,0; indexA = 0
posB 0,0; indexB = 0

posA 8,0; indexA = 8 (end of first row)
posB 2,0; indexB = 2

posA 0,1; indexA = 9
posB 0,0; indexB = 0 (still closer to the bottom point)

posA 0,3; indexA = 27
posB 0,1; indexB = 3

posA 8,8; indexA = 80 (last point)
posB 2,2; indexB = 8

so far I have:
indexA = posAX + (posAY * SizeAX)

what I've tried (and of course failed):
indexB = (int) (indexA * (SizeBX * SizeBY / (SizeAX * SizeAY)) + 0.5) // Only appears to work for the first row and last value.. but this clearly doesn't work - but I am curious as to how exactly it maps the two together, but I'll look into that after I fix it..

I didn't have access to posAY or posAX, just indexA, but I should be able to break it down using mod and remainder, right? or is there a more efficient faster way?  A

I also tried this:

indexB = (posAY * SizeBY / SizeAY) * SizeBY + (posAX * SizeBX / SizeAX)

I think the problem is that I need to round the X and Y indexes separate then use SizeBX and SizeBY afterwards?

An extra caveat is that ArrayA and ArrayB come from larger data set that both sample a larger space.  Since the rectangle is arbitrary, either ArrayA or ArrayB could have the point closest to the bounds of the rectangle, leading to other issues as to which way the nearest neighbor is really grabbing.  I am not sure about how to address this, either.

Answer (score 0):

What you essentially mean is that you have two grids with different spacing covering the same area and given an index of a gridpoint in one of them you want to find the closest one in the second. Like this:

```
int posBX = (int)floorf((float(posAX) / float(sizeAX - 1)) * float(sizeBX - 1) + 0.5f);
int posBY = (int)floorf((float(posAY) / float(sizeAY - 1)) * float(sizeBY - 1) + 0.5f);
int indexB = posBX + posBY * sizeBX;
```

To get `posAX` and `posAY` from `indexA`:

```
posAX = indexA % sizeAX;
posAY = indexA / sizeAX;
```

To do bilinear interpolation:

```
float bx = (float(posAX) / float(sizeAX - 1)) * float(sizeBX - 1);
float by = (float(posAY) / float(sizeAY - 1)) * float(sizeBY - 1);
int x = min(int(floorf(bx)), sizeBX - 2); //x + 1 must be <= sizeBX - 1
int y = min(int(floorf(by)), sizeBY - 2); //y + 1 must be <= sizeBY - 1
float s = bx - float(x);
float t = by - float(y);
float v[4];
v[0] = arrayB[x + y * sizeBX];
v[1] = arrayB[x + 1 + y * sizeBX];
v[2] = arrayB[x + (y + 1) * sizeBX];
v[3] = arrayB[x + 1 + (y + 1) * sizeBX];
float result = (v[0] * (1.0f - s) + v[1] * s) * (1.0f - t) +
               (v[2] * (1.0f - s) + v[3] * s) * t;
```

Comment: I was almost there but was having problems of deciding where to put the -1's!  Thanks!

Any clue as to what to do about the last part? I fear that it may be picking the wrong point in some cases, but maybe it actually handles itself automatically this way?

Comment: My slightly more complicated answer below performs nearest-neighbor interpolation, and should agree in the case that SizeBX divides SizeAX and SizeBY divides SizeAY evenly.

Comment: Hmm, do you mean that the bounds of area `A` and area `B` doesn't necessarily line up?

Comment: I'm assuming your answer is correct (I didn't check); you're just rounding to the nearest location.  I'm taking the average of the four closest points in `B`.  Take, for example, `A` as a 3 by 4 array, and `B` as 11 by 5.  In other words, I figure the horizontal and vertical resolution of `B` may vary by different ratios compared to `A`.

Comment: @wrang-wrang I understand your bilinear interpolation, my comment was directed to the comment from the OP.

Comment: Well, the way that the rectangle is being drawn, it can lead to say ArrayA having the closest points to the left edge of the rectangle, the right edge of the rectangle, neither, or both. The same for the top and bottom. The middle two cases are ambiguous (left or right edge?) as we only have the sizes. Would this create any problems?

Comment: Do `ArrayA` and `ArrayB` cover *exactly* the same area?

Comment: No, ArrayA and ArrayB come from setA and setB which map the same larger area.  An arbitrary rectangle is drawn on the larger area which gives subsets ArrayA and ArrayB, meaning that the points on the edge could be either from ArrayA or ArrayB.

Comment: Hmm, this certainly throws a wrench in the machinery. To get a correct match you have to know the min and max positions of the two grids in world space. Do you have this information?

Comment: I may be able to have this data passed - if so, how to correct for it?  Would we have to take into account the real grid spacing between A and B? I feel that the current code will be slightly off with nearest neighbor due to size B or size A are +/-2 in relation to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Those are some revolting names you've chosen, but at least they're defined.

I think you want to go through (x,y) in [0...1]x[0...1] real coordinate space; that is, the lower right of A should grab the value from the lower right of B, and likewise for mid-upper-left, etc.  This means that you should think of the outside edges of points in your array as the 0-width point samples values at the edges of the [0...1]x[0...1] box; i.e. if you have a 3x3 array, there's one point at (0.5,0.5) and the rest are along an edge.

I'll assume your 2d B array has real values in it, so that it makes sense to interpolate; because the arrays are of different sizes

Here's the scheme for going from a

indexA -> (posAX,posAY) -> (x,y) -> (fracBX,fracBY) ->(by nearest neighbor interpolation) value from ArrayB

Important: (fracBX,fracBY) are real-valued coordinates in the box [0...SizeBX-1]x[0...SizeBY-1].

Let's take it one step at a time.  Assuming I understood you, values are in memory in left->right, top->bottom (english reading) order, just like standard C arrays.  Then:

```
unsigned posAX=indexA%SizeAX;
unsigned posAY=indexA/SizeAX;
```

Now, let's map to (x,y):

```
double x=posAX/(SizeAX-1.0); // we get double division when we subtract by 1.0
double y=posAY/(SizeAY-1.0);
```

Now, to (fracBX,fracBY), where 0<=fracBX<=SizeBX and 0<=fracBY<=SizeBY:

```
double fracBX=x*(SizeBX-1);
double fracBY=y*(SizeBY-1);
```

Now, to interpolate between the (up to 4) nearest integral points in the B array:

```
unsigned intBX=(unsigned)fracBX;
double aBX=fracBX-intBX;
unsigned intBY=(unsigned)fracBY;
double aBY=fracBY-intBY;
double *bv=ArrayB+(intBX*sizeBY)+intBY;
#define INTERP(alpha,v1,v2) ((1-alpha)*v1+alpha*v2)
#define INTERPI(alpha,i1,i2) (alpha>0 ? INTERP(alpha,bv[i1],bv[i2] : bv[i1])
double v0=INTERPI(aBX,0,1);
double value=fracBY>0 ? INTERP(aBY,v0,INTERPI(aBX,sizeBY,sizeBY+1)) : v0;
```

value is your answer.  The checks for the fractional positions aBX and aBY being 0 are needed to prevent accessing values off the end of the array (which can cause a segfault even though the values are ignored by multiplying by 0).  Or you can simplify things by allocating 1 more row/column than you need.

bv[0] is the ArrayB[intBX][intBY], bv[1] is one to the right, bv[sizeBY] is one down, and bv[sizeBY+1] is one down and to the right.  (aBX,aBY) is another point in [0...1]x[0...1], but this time bounded by those four adjacent points in ArrayB.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, billinear interpolation would probably be my next step after this!!

Comment: This interpolation doesn't work if `unsigned intBY=(unsigned)fracBY` end up exactly as `(SizeBY-1)` (`posAY` on the border). In this case you will sample row `SizeBY` which is outside the array.

Comment: (Check my answer for another version)

Comment: In that case alpha would be 0, so only the upper/left address would be used.  I agree that it requires care, but I took that care.